# X3D - Modify specific nodes

Tags: javascript, xml, html, x3d

I have defined scene for example, which is either written in a seperate x3d file or prewritten in the loaded html site.

For example like this:

```
<x3d id="x3dStyle"> 
     <scene>
     </scene>
</x3d>
```

I would like to have some kind of xml tree view where I can select a node of the tree, like the node "scene", and add to this node via some textboxes and a button a cube for example.

So first things first: How do I select a node like the node "scene"? How do I add a sub-node the parent node with specific attributes? How does the workflow differ if I load a external X3D file? How do I differ 2 nodes which have the same tag for example like ("shape") in this case, where I would like for e.g. change the color of the first shape to green and the one of the second shape to red:

```
<x3d id="x3dStyle"> 
    <scene>
        <shape>
            <appearance>
                <material id ="color" diffuseColor='1 0 0'></material>
            </appearance>
            <box></box>
        </shape>
        <transform translation='-3 0 0'>
            <shape>
                <appearance>
                    <material diffuseColor='0 1 0'></material>
                </appearance>
                <cone></cone>
            </shape>
        </transform>
</x3d>
```

I also would like to garant the user a xml tree view of the x3d scene, so that the user can select a specific node, do you have any suggestions which kind of plugin is preferable for this kind of job?